# java swing getting a value from a JTextField from a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I know that if I need to change `JTextField` value from a different thread I need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call. But if I need to get that value from a different thread, can I just use `textfield.getText()` or I need to use some sort of `invokeLater` call? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even something as simple as getText() should be called from the event dispatch thread.

If you're in another thread, you can use [invokeAndWait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
AtomicReference<String> textHolder = new AtomicReference<>();

EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textHolder.set(someTextField.getText());
    }
});

String text = textHolder.get();
```

Comment: Does it actually make sure that textHolder[0] is synchronized? Most definitely the array reference textHolder is fully initialized before sending it onto the EDT, but is textHolder[0] value guaranteed not to be "stuck" in EDT cache?

Comment: @PKua Interesting point.  An AtomicReference would be safer.

Comment: Now that I think, invokeAndWait must use some wait/notify mechanism. Is it not enough to guarantee a happens-before relationship? Anyway, AtomicReference is definitely a safe bet

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with the results of the getText() call being possibly indeterminate (ie unordered), then it would be permissible to use a different thread to get the value.

Comment: in what situations can it be indeterminate? if it changes in between the call?

Comment: When you are multi-threading, you have no certainty about when methods / procedures will be called, when they will finish, or what state an object ungoing a "write" / modification is going to be in when you do your read. Possible changes that could be occuring while you are calling getText() include changing the JTextfield's document, the document's contents, the cursor position ,etc. BUT... Since String is immutable in Java, if all you care about is getText(), this is guarenteed to be thread-safe, again, because of String's immutability

Comment: OK, what would you recommend doing then?